# SQL Select from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

[image]

I would like to write a query that outputs the records that have occurencies for both years 2000 and 2001 only.

In this case, the output would be

```
Bb 2000
Bb 2001
```

because only the records with the name Bb have occurencies on both years.

I have tried Subqueries and Joins but haven't had success, since the two columns are not Primary Keys nor Foreign Keys.

Thank you.

Comment: What if `Bb` also happened to have a record for `2005`, would you want it returned as well, or only the `2000/2001` records?  Or, would that extra `2005` record actually disqualify any `Bb` rows from being returned altogether?

Comment: I have already solved my problem based on the solution provided by @vkp.
But to answer your question, my table can only have '2000' or '2001' in the _year_ column. No other year will appear. However, if it was possible to have other values for _year_ then I would want to get the records that had more than one year for the same _name_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `intersect` to do this.

```
select x.name, x.year from
(
select name from table where year = 2000
intersect
select name from table where year = 2001
) t join table x on t.name = x.name
```

Answer (score 1):

> My table can only have `2000` or `2001` in the `year` column. No other year will appear. However, if it was possible to have other values for `year` then I would want to get the records that had more than one year for the same `name`.

If you ever have the need to deal with other years as described in your comment, then this is the query I would use:

```
select id, name, year
  from (select id, name, year,
               count(distinct year) over (partition by name) as distinct_year_cnt
          from table_name)
 where distinct_year_cnt > 1
```